# Get the title and other metadata of a PDF using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive, pdf

I have a lot of research papers in my google drive. They are all in PDF format. To better manage this large collection of papers (>1k), I want to make a simple table (a Google sheet), in which I would like to have the titles (not file names) and other metadata (e.g. year of publication, authors, etc.) of the PDFs with their corresponding URLs on Google drive.

Using Google Apps Script, I can get the URLs of all the PDFs without breaking sweat. However, getting the titles of the PDFs seems to be a difficult task. I wonder if there is any solution for this that uses Google Apps Script or some other approach.

One possible solution would involve patching together different APIs. I am thinking that getting the titles of the PDFs would be possible by (**1**) first taking few lines from the 1st page of the PDF, (**2**) searching them over the Google using Google search API. This should give me the title of the PDF, but not always. Once I have the title then, I could (**3**) get the metadata of the PDF using APIs of databases such as [PubMed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) or [Crossref](https://www.crossref.org/). This is a kind of solution that is not going to work for all the PDFs. I wonder if there is any existing solution for this that might work better than the solution I am thinking of.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by title? Are you referring to the file name? if that is the case just use the getName() method of Class File. By the other hand have you already tried the Google Drive advanced service? In either case, please show what you tried. and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Also please be more specific about what other metadata you want to get.

Comment: I did not mean the file name but the the title of the document. In a typical research paper, it is commonly located at the top of the first page.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but the question doesn't look to be good fit for this site, for one side because questions about APIs are off-topic an by the other because the question needs more focus.

Comment: Thinking out loud... What if one imported a pdf into Google Docs? Would there be consistent parameter(s) to identify and capture the Title?  If answer is yes, then an apps script might be a solution. There _are_ solutions for this scenario. To name one Yagisanatode has a post [Google Apps Script: Extract Specific Data From a PDF and insert it into a Google Sheet](https://yagisanatode.com/2020/06/13/google-apps-script-extract-specific-data-from-a-pdf-and-insert-it-into-a-google-sheet/). Have you researched these alternatives?